# .Net Core 3.1 Identity Customizing UserManager FindByIdAsync Method

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have been trying to use UserManager and RoleManager. I have implemented my identity classes that have an **int primary key**.

For instance, when I would like to use UserManager FindByIdAsync method, it is still **required string userId parameter**, but I want to use an int parameter. How can I change this ? Actually, I have not customized UserManager or UserStore before.

In addition to all of these, I am using LinqToDB.Identity.

```
 var appUser = _userService.FindByIdAsync(); //must be used an int parameter
```

Here is my AppUser class.

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>, IEntity
{
   [Required, Identity]
   [Key]
   public override int Id { get => base.Id; set => base.Id = value; }
   public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
   public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

   public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }
   public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
   public int? StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my AddLinqToDBStores implementation.

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds authentication service
/// </summary>
/// <param name="services">Collection of service descriptors</param>
public static void AddDevPlatformAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;

        //TODO
        //options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; 
        //options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
        //options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);

    }).AddLinqToDBStores<int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppUserToken, AppRoleClaim>(new
    IdentityConnectionFactory(new SqlServerDataProvider(ProviderName.SqlServer, SqlServerVersion.v2017), "SqlServerIdentity", DataSettingsManager.LoadSettings().ConnectionString))
    .AddUserStore<LinqToDB.Identity.UserStore<int, AppUser, AppRole, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppUserToken>>()
    .AddUserManager<UserManager<AppUser>>()
    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<AppRole>>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();

    // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers

    JwtTokenDefinitions.LoadFromConfiguration(configuration);
    services.ConfigureJwtAuthentication();
    services.ConfigureJwtAuthorization();
}
```

_userManager.FindByIdAsync() as I said, I need to use **an int parameter** for all userManager and roleManager methods.

How can I handle it ?

Best Regards

Comment: Why not simply cast the int to a string and pass that?

Comment: Casting the int to a sting parameter and passing through it work fine, but I would like to do it more professionally, and I would like to learn customizing identity managers. Such as, roleManager, userManager.  @Dennis1679